# Slick 3.2 CodeGenerator Tool hardcodes the database name in the autogenerated code

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am using slick 3.2 code generation tool and I auto generated the code against my production database. In the generated code I can see

```
class BarActivity(_tableTag: Tag) extends profile.api.Table[BarActivityRow](_tableTag, Some("foo_prod"), "bar_activity") {
```

Here foo_prod is the database against which the code generator ran.

The problem is that for multiple environments my databases are named differently. So dev database is foo_dev and qa database is foo_qa.

I don't want to generate the database file each and every-time I switch environments. I want to use the same generated code across environments.

I think slick should have allowed us to specify the database name from the connection properties.

So with auto generated code, how do I write a problem which has two connections. One to read data from prod and second to write data to dev? Should I generate the code twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the output as you wish :
The default value of where you're looking at is in `AbstractSourceCodeGenerator.scala` -> `TableClassDef` trait, in the `code` method.

So, assuming you have a class like 
`class MyGenerator extends SourceCodeGenerator(model) {`
you can add in it

```
override def Table = new Table(_) {
  override def TableClass = new TableClassDef {
    override def code =  {
       val prns = parents.map(" with " + _).mkString("")
       s"""class $name(_tableTag: Tag) extends profile.api.Table[$elementType](_tableTag, ${hereGoesTheDatabaseNameAndTheTableNameComaSeparated})$prns {
  ${indent(body.map(_.mkString("\n")).mkString("\n\n"))}"""
         }
      }
    }
```

In your case, you may want to have the variable hereGoesTheDatabaseNameAndTheTableNameComaSeparated fetch the database name from some config file or environment variable for example ?

Full disclaimer : I never customized this part myself, but I can't see a big reason this wouldn't work.